# Plot word distribution / correspondence analysis as bi-plot in quanteda r

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda, correspondence-analysis

I think this question is more one of orientation/model choice than code. I want to plot a correspondence analysis but I want to end up with a two-dimensional word association plot. Two examples are this, in Schonhardt-Bailey 2008:

["word distribution in correspondence space"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdEI4.png)

And this, in Anstead 2017:

[Correspondence analysis showing "clusters of language use"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPgJP.jpg)

I have successfully run textplot_scale1d() and created a correspondence analysis, but this is a different plot to what I had in mind, because of the focus on position of speakers/documents etc (e.g. https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/ca/ ). So I figure my problem here is about the model I'm fitting, and the model that I actually want possibly having a different name in quanteda.

I'd really welcome any help to:

(1) plot these word distribution correspondence analyses, not the positions.

And at a stretch, ideally what I would like to get to is:

(2) How to make a more advanced version of these word distribution plots, to incorporate a first step using a dictionary, so the ultimate word distribution correspondence analysis shows words that co-occur with the dictionary keywords.

Thanks very much for any advice you can offer.

Comment: The `textmodel_ca()` basically passes through a dfm to `ca::ca()` and that package has biplot functions defined for those classes of objects. `quanteda.textplots()` does not (yet).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.